# get data-id from the last class only?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to always get the last data-id.
even if I add more classes with more data-id dinamically.

how to get the last data-id value not the first?

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200){

    var variable = $('.report').data("id");
    alert(variable);

       }
    });

    });

// how to get data from the last one only?

<li class="report" data-id="602532">Report inappropriate</li>
<li class="report" data-id="602530">Report inappropriate</li>
<li class="report" data-id="602529">Report inappropriate</li>
<li class="report" data-id="602531">Report inappropriate</li>
<li class="report" data-id="602575">Report inappropriate</li>
<li class="report" data-id="602557">Report inappropriate</li>
<li class="report" data-id="602574">Report inappropriate</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7m50Lyx1/

Comment: `$('.report:last')...`

Comment: or `$('.report').last()`

Comment: neither of those suggestions will work in the document ready event, because they won't fire after new elements are added "dinamically"... of course, the question needs to be clearer as to when it would be called after new elements are added

Comment: How do you plan on handling new elements being added? Currently your code only works on the document ready event, but you mention you want it to work with dynamic elements. Those two things don't add up, so please explain what you expect to happen when a new element is added, and more importantly show us how those new elements will be created. Or perhaps when you say dynamically you just mean that you won't know how many are listed at the time of document ready. In which case the posted answer is probably fine

Comment: @musefan I edited it! sorry! it will call a ajax to add more li there. and always I'd like to get last id to call more results

Comment: @RickJoe: Fair enough... just use either of the selectors in the comments

Comment: thank you very much @musefan

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var variable = $('.report').last("id");
alert(variable);

});
```

Comment: You should really test your code... as should the person who upvoted.. your code does not alert the `id`, as per the question requirements